# Why isn't there a cloudformation for eks pod configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am deploying a EKS cluster and a fargate profile with cloudformation. But I can't find a cloudformation type for Fargate Pod configuration. When I search the doc, it always mention that to use `kubectl` command to deploy them.

Is this the only way to deploy my application container to EKS? If yes, how can I create infrastructure as code?

And how can I put the pod and every container in cloudformation stack? I'd like to tear down everything by deleting cloudformation stack.

Comment: Your prods run on your nodes. So if you delete the stack, nods will be deleted along with your pods.

Comment: Do you mean I still need to provision node even for Fargate?

Comment: Sorry,  my mistake in comment. But still, if you delete your eks stack, your prods on fargate will also go down, won't they?

Comment: I didn't try that but my question is why cloudformation doesn't support deploy pod?

Comment: Becase EKS is for managing control plane and nodes. Its not about what and how are you going to deploy your pods on them.

Comment: that means I have to put `kubetcl apply ` command in my CI/CD?